# Trouble connecting to LibreOffice Base database in split database mode using HSQL 2.2.8

Tags: ubuntu, database, libreoffice-base

I am trying to install a split database (starting with a file copy) using an upgrade to HSQL 2.2.8.  I got HSQL 2.2.8, and have followed the instructions from another post on this site ( [How to set up the jdbc driver to connect to hsqldb from libreoffice?](https://superuser.com/questions/555325/how-to-set-up-the-jdbc-driver-to-connect-to-hsqldb-from-libreoffice/560192#560192) ) to get the Class Path working fine when I pointed it to the correct location for my HSQL 2.2.8 and restarted LibreOffice. In Edit > Database > Properties I used Test Class and it successfully connected to the JDBC driver.  That part worked fine.  But then when I test the connection it keeps saying that the file is not found. I checked the file path again and again, tried moving it to different locations but its not working. I first had tried it with the mydb.file.odb that I found on a LibreOffice/OpenOffice forum (sorry can't recall which) and that connection would not work. So I copied the Data Class URL from the other post mentioned above changing the file path as needed and it is still not finding it.

The error message I get is:
SQL Status: S1000
Error code: -451

Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@d016958c[file =/Home/Databases/ManualDB/ManualDB.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Home/Databases/ManualDB/ManualDB.lck (No such file or directory)

I am running LibreOffice 4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck using the fully-qualified name of the Java class, org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.

Point 1...
Try using this :  org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver , (Very Case sensitive), for your class.
This always connects in Base and other sql clients.

Also the mydb.odb has been updated.
The forum was probably,
http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=61183.
You can get updated odb here.

Check what you are doing against their tutorial.

You need to have a folder to contain the database files called database. Your "*.odb" file lives outside that folder. You should have another folder called driver in which you put the hsqldb.jar. This is the driver path to point to.

I am also struggling with this split database/odb/Base problem as I want the portabilty that LibreOffice  and split odb's offer.

Point 2...
Last point: Get a current hsqldb driver 2.3.0 upwards. They say not to use 2.2.9 as there is a bug. The 2.3.0 addresses an issue with Base not doing autovalue in split odb's. So get this driver.

This should remove your obstacles.

I have tested/am using LibOffice 4 on opensuse 12.3